# Cocoa Touch - Incompatible types in assignment

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios

I am trying to convert hex color values into floats.  I have a DataController class with a method like so:

```
+(float)floatFromHexColorInteger:(float)hexFloat {
    float newColorFloat = hexFloat / 255.0f;
    return newColorFloat;
}
```

I want to use it to easily get a color value between 0.0 and 1.0, so I can use it like so:

```
float colorFloat = [DataController floatFromHexColorInteger:79.0f];
//error on line above is:
//Classes/RootViewController.m:53: error: incompatible types in assignment
self.navigationController.toolbar.tintColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:colorFloat green:colorFloat blue:colorFloat alpha:1.0f];
```

I'm getting a compiler error (2) on the first line, about incompatible types.  Can anyone figure out why?

Comment: What is the exact compiler error message you get?

Comment: Please post the actual error message you're getting.

Comment: Is floatFromHexColorInteger: declared somewhere? If so, check the return type here too.

Comment: Does it say `+(float)floatFromHexColorInteger:(float)hexFloat` too or the return types differ in .h and .m?

Comment: Yea the return was incorrect in the header. Works now! Feel free to answer on stack overflow so I can vote you

Comment: Incidentally - I'd expect a method called floatFromHexColorInteger to take an integer as its argument, not a float. Suggest you either a) pass in an integer and cast it to a float internally, or b) rename the method.

Comment: Duly noted. I will probably refactor it

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `+(float)floatFromHexColorInteger:(float)hexFloat` is declared somewhere (in the .h file for example), you should check that the return type is `float` too.

If it's something else, the compiler may throw an error.